# FTC Android Studio User code threw an uncaught exception: NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am on the High School FIRST Robotics team at my school, team 5108. I've been working on an autonomous program that could be adaptable to most any robot and very simple to alter. basically all the user has to input is the starting point of the robot, based on a coordinate plane overlayed on the playing field.

However I continue having this error when I try to run it. I have looked over the code multiple times and have no errors or warning, I also used the code inspection that android studio provides and changed everything it recomended with no luck. If there is any questions about the program just ask, I'm rather new so some may not be as good as it could be.

```
package com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.opmodes;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpMode;
import com.qualcomm.hardware.HiTechnicNxtCompassSensor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotorController;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by Tyler Eads on 12/7/15.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SmartAutonomous  extends OpMode {

    private double distance;
    private double angle;
    private double currentx;
    private double currenty;
    private double targetx;
    private double targety;





    private HiTechnicNxtCompassSensor compassSensor;

    private final double compassvalue = compassSensor.getDirection();


    private final int countsperrotation = 1440;


    // INSERT ROBOT INFORMATION HERE...

    private final double wheeldiameter = 3.0;      //Insert Wheel Diameter Here
    private final double circumference = wheeldiameter * Math.PI;
    private final double gearratio = 1;         //write as fraction

    //END ROBOT INFORMATION


    private void distance(double currentx, double currenty, double targetx, double targety) {

        distance = Math.sqrt(((currentx - targetx) * (currentx - targetx)) + ((currenty - targety) * (currenty - targety)));

    }

    private void angle(double currentx, double currenty, double targetx, double targety) {

        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((targety-currenty)/(targetx-currentx)));

    }

    private final double wheelrotations = distance / circumference;
    private final double motorrotations = wheelrotations * gearratio;
    private final double encodercounts = motorrotations * countsperrotation;




    public enum Facing {North, NorthEast, East, SouthEast, South, SouthWest, West, NorthWest}
    private Facing facing;

    public enum RelativePosition {North, NorthEast, East, SouthEast, South, SouthWest, West, NorthWest}
    private RelativePosition relativeposition;





    private void facing() {
        if (260 <= compassvalue && compassvalue <= 264) {
            facing = Facing.North;
        } else if (264 < compassvalue && compassvalue < 348) {
            facing = Facing.NorthEast;
        } else if (348 <= compassvalue && compassvalue <= 352) {
            facing = Facing.East;
        } else if (352 < compassvalue && compassvalue < 88) {
            facing = Facing.SouthEast;
        } else if (88 <= compassvalue && compassvalue <= 92) {
            facing = Facing.South;
        } else if (92 < compassvalue && compassvalue < 178) {
            facing = Facing.SouthWest;
        } else if (178 <= compassvalue && compassvalue <= 182) {
            facing = Facing.West;
        } else if (182 < compassvalue && compassvalue < 260) {
            facing = Facing.NorthWest;
        }

    }

    private void pointrelative() {
        switch (facing) {
            case North:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;

                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                }

                break;

            case NorthEast:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                }

                break;

            case East:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                }

                break;

            case SouthEast:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                }

                break;

            case South:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                }

                break;

            case SouthWest:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                }

                break;

            case West:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast
                    ;
                }

                break;

            case NorthWest:

                if (currenty < targety && currentx == targetx) {

                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthEast;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.East;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthEast;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx < targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.South;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx == targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.SouthWest;
                } else if (currenty > targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.West;
                } else if (currenty == targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.NorthWest;
                } else if (currenty < targety && currentx > targetx) {
                    relativeposition = RelativePosition.North;
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void action() {

        DcMotor rightdrive = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("right_drive");
        DcMotor leftdrive = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("left_drive");

        rightdrive.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.REVERSE);

        leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RESET_ENCODERS);
        rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RESET_ENCODERS);

        compassSensor = (HiTechnicNxtCompassSensor) hardwareMap.compassSensor.get("compass");
        double fullpower = 1.0;

        switch(relativeposition) {


            case North:

                rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                break;

            case NorthEast:

                if (compassvalue > compassvalue - (90-angle)) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

            case East:

                if (compassvalue > compassvalue - 90) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

            case SouthEast:

                if (compassvalue > compassvalue - (90+angle)) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

            case South:

                if (compassvalue > compassvalue - 180) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

            case SouthWest:

                if (compassvalue < compassvalue + (90+angle) ) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

            case West:

                if (compassvalue < compassvalue + 90) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

            case NorthWest:

                if (compassvalue < compassvalue + (90-angle)) {
                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(-fullpower);
                }
                else {
                    rightdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);
                    leftdrive.setTargetPosition((int) encodercounts);

                    rightdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
                    leftdrive.setChannelMode(DcMotorController.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

                    rightdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                    leftdrive.setPower(fullpower);
                }

                break;

        }



    }



    private void smartmove() {
        distance(currentx, currenty, targetx, targety);
        angle(currentx, currenty, targetx, targety);
        facing();
        pointrelative();
        action();

        currentx = targetx;     //Sets target point to new current position
        currenty = targety;
    }

    private final ArrayList<Integer> Step = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void init() {


    }

    @Override
    public void loop() {



        int size = Step.size();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            int element = Step.get(i);

            switch (element) {
                case 1:

                    currentx = 134;
                    currenty = 60;

                    targetx = 108;
                    targety = 60;

                    smartmove();
                    break;
                case 2:

                    targetx = 59.5;
                    targety = 107.5;

                    smartmove();

                    break;
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't an much of an answer but I can't comment

Your code is very long with a lot of redundancy(you should avoid this but that's not the point) so you really need to include something about the error you're getting besides the fact that it's nullpointer(stacktrace, image if you have to). It also doesn't help that you spread out your fields across your code so they're even harder to find.

best guess: it doesn't look like you ever instantiated your enums

```
public enum Facing {North, NorthEast, East, SouthEast, South, SouthWest, West, NorthWest}
private Facing facing;
//naming this facing is also a pretty bad idea when you have a facing() function
public enum RelativePosition {North, NorthEast, East, SouthEast, South, SouthWest, West, NorthWest}
private RelativePosition relativeposition;
```

but that's not much more than a guess, this is really hard to read